# Why is font not available in ASP.NET code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts

I have an ASP.NET site where I generate ID cards for users. I use a Bitmap object and call Graphics.DrawString to write various bits of text on the image. I have used various fonts to do this for quite a while, without any fuss.

A customer has now asked me to use the Roboto font for their card. I downloaded it from Google and installed it on my system - it appears in the control panel and is available to other apps. However, my card generator can't access it - it defaults to Microsoft Sans Serif. I used `foreach (FontFamily family in FontFamily.Families)` to see if it was listed, and it was not included in the list. I tried the same thing in a WinForms app, and the font *was* included in the list.

So, my question is, why can't I access this font from within an ASP.NET process? Is there some difference in the way fonts are supported between ASP.NET and WinForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the asp.net is run under specific pool, and this pool is logged in as different user - that probably have not installed that fonts.

So check under which user your pool is run, and install for that user that font.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how to install a font for another user, especially an app pool user which cannot log in. I tried modifying the security settings on the font to allow the app pool user, but that did not help. I have done this same thing with other fonts in the past, and they have worked correctly without having to do anything other than restart IIS so the process recognized them.

Comment: @Ray, maybe you install them as shortcut, maybe you place them on fonts directory with out the correct permissions, maybe its just not register for the other users - on windows 10 if you right click on a font file is ask you if you like to "install it for all users". You can use a pool user that you create and you can login with that account to double check the fonts

Comment: I have never used 'install for all users' before, and never had a problem. I tried it anyway - I removed the font and re-installed. No luck - same problem. In the security settings for the font file, the 'Users' group is granted read and execute permission.

Comment: @Ray Other reason -> maybe you use some string with encode that fonts not have

Comment: No - my test harness uses the same strings every time. And 99.999% of real uses are plain US ASCII characters. Thanx for taking your time to help on this.

Comment: Six months later, I have the same problem, google it, find my old question, try the solution suggested by @Aristos - and it worked. So, answer accepted - thanx.